# Unable to bootstrap Nest application. "TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined"

Tags: node.js, rest, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Recently I wrote for myself a demo-app (full code: https://github.com/aversilov/parley-fork) based on this Ahamed Foysal's example (https://www.codementor.io/foysalit/rest-api-with-mongodb-and-nest-js-hto6x5120). As you know NestJS is a very young framework and there are catastrophicaly small number of tutorials & demo-apps for learn it.
So, I create all files in the project, run mongod in separate terminal window, and run app:
`npm run start`
But the app is crashed with:

Error output

[image]

P.S. I checked - circular references in my codebase don't exists ([Vue + typescript - TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992278/vue-typescript-typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-un)).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `database.module.ts` do a

```
@Module({
    components: [...databaseProviders],
    exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

three dots are required

Then in `posts.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [DatabaseModule],
    controllers: [PostsController],
    components: [PostsService, ...postsProviders],
})
export class PostsModule {}
```

again three dots are required

in `posts.providers.ts` replace `DB_CONNECTION` with `DB_PROVIDER`

Why three dots ? If you will look in `posts.providers.ts` it exports an array, and you want your module to import each provider separately, not the array.

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for your reply. Sorry, it's just typo in my code. Originally modules look like this: [link] (http://i.piccy.info/i9/c813edf495be3cdfbde25ae1e4182aa9/1522756037/35887/1234504/2_800.jpg) and [link] (http://i.piccy.info/i9/5b812bb9d1ca0b125abc7d4d872e91ca/1522756215/45295/1234504/3_800.jpg). But, yes of couse: you are right - in `post.providers.ts` error/typo presense as you mentioned above. Thank you again. Seems to be this my question is resolved.