# Shallow mounting in Vue, stubs not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'd like to write a Jest test for a Vue component, which renders a subcomponent. The component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="add-to-cart-position">
    <a :href="item.url">
      <picture-comp
        class="add-to-cart-position__image"
        :srcset-mobile="item.imageUrlMobile"
        :srcset-desktop="item.imageUrl"
      />
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import BasketItem from '../interfaces/BasketItem';
  import PictureComp from '../pictureComp/pictureComp.vue';

  @Component({
    name: 'add-to-cart-position',
    components: {
      PictureComp
    }
  })
  export default class AddToCartPosition extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    item: BasketItem;
  }
</script>
```

According to the [docs](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/stubbing-components.html#automatically-stubbing-with-shallowmount) I can use `shallowMount` to automatically stub all subcomponents, which is exactly what I want. So my test looks like this:

```
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
import AddToCartPosition from 'AddToCartPosition.vue';
import {mockBasketItem} from '/__mocks__/data/basketItem.mock';

describe('addToCartPosition', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(AddToCartPosition, {
    propsData: {
      basketItem: mockBasketItem()
    }
  });

  it('matches the snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But when I run this test I get an error and the error is in the `PictureComp` subcomponent, which should not be rendered at all. Why does the automatic stubbing not work?

I also tried `mount` and manual stubbing, but it does not change anything. The error message stays the same.

Error message:

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)

  34 |       >
  35 |       <source
> 36 |         :srcset="srcLg"
     |            ^
  37 |         media="(min-width: 767px)"
  38 |       >
  39 |       <img

  at extendStatics (pictureComp/pictureComp.vue:36:12)
  at Object.<anonymous>.__extends (pictureComp/pictureComp.vue:40:5)
  at pictureComp/pictureComp.vue:62:1
  at pictureComp/pictureComp.vue:105:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (pictureComp/pictureComp.vue:137:3)
  at addToCartPosition/addToCartPosition.vue:70:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (addToCartPosition/addToCartPosition.vue:106:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/components/addToCartPosition.test.ts:2:1)
```

Comment: It's not evident that the error occurs because pictureComp renders. Since you're using shallowMount, I expect it not to. The error likely occurs on pictureComp import and there's nothing shallowMount can help with. Please, provide pictureComp.vue because it's relevant.

Comment: This is correct. The error was indeed in the subcomponent - not while rendering it but at import time. The error message is just very, very misleading.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. extendStatics and setPrototypeOf  suggest that this happens when a class is defined. Makes sense since you're using class components.

Answer (score 0):

This took me ages to understand but I eventually see what you mean by the comments on the question.

For me this was that I needed to [set an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953365/5766011) as one of my modules was expecting to reference a value that did not exist.

This is checked when the Import command is run even if when you come to mount your component the import would not be required due to some form of test double.

Comment: In my case it was a problem concerning Vue, Jest and Typescript like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992278/vue-typescript-typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-un/  Jest and TS don't like the Vue default export. All components need a little extra care.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Jest doesn't know what the relation between `picture-comp` and `PictureComp` is. If this even works in Vue, then my guess is that Vue knows how to resolve kebab-case to PascalCase.
At any rate, I would expect it to work if you register the component correctly:

```
components: {
  'picture-comp': PictureComp
}
```

or, use `<PictureComp>` instead of `<picture-comp>` in your template.