# typescript, vue, can't run jest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build ",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --watch --mode=development",
    "test": "jest tests/.*test.ts",
    "watchTest": "jest --watch tests/.*test.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.6.4",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-browser-acl": "^0.13.5",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.16.0",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.6.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuex": "latest",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.16.1",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "1.5.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~2.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-imports",
      {
        "quasar": {
          "transform": "quasar/dist/babel-transforms/imports.js",
          "preventFullImport": true
        }
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "node",
      "@types/jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

To be honest I even not sure what this error mean. Jest don't understand typeSript? Maybe vue? When I tried to find some answer in google, normally people have problem with "import" keywords, not some variable. I tried to add babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties, but it was worst. And because I even don't understand this error and can't find similar in net it's hard to do something. Maybe someone help.

Comment: Please show how your component looks like, especially how you do the Vue import. Maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992278/vue-typescript-typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-un/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should install `ts-jest`

And add transform and moduleFileExtensions in package.json

```
{
  "jest": {
      "transform": {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
        '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
      },
      "moduleFileExtensions": ['ts', 'js', 'vue']
  }
}
```